# Akeneo 2.1.4 : How can I use an attribute value as label for a product model in the datagrid?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, akeneo

When I use product models in Akeneo 2.1.4, I see the code of the product model in the label-column. But I want to show the value of a specific attribute there; `name` for example or `group name`. How can I achieve this?

**Edit:**

I tried extending the class and rewriting it in my own `entities.yml`:

```
parameters:
    # Rewrite product model so we can override the getLabel()-method:
    pim_catalog.entity.product_model.class: Vendor\Bundle\AppBundle\Model\ProductModel
```

But then I get the error:

```
The class 'Vendor\Bundle\AppBundle\Model\ProductModel' was not found in the chain configured namespaces 
    Gedmo\Tree\Entity, 
    Oro\Bundle\ConfigBundle\Entity, 
    Oro\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity, 
    Pim\Bundle\CustomEntityBundle\Entity, 
    FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Entity, 
    Pim\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity, 
    Pim\Bundle\ApiBundle\Entity, 
    Pim\Bundle\CatalogBundle\Entity, 
    Pim\Bundle\CommentBundle\Entity, 
    Pim\Bundle\DataGridBundle\Entity, 
    Pim\Bundle\NotificationBundle\Entity, 
    Akeneo\Component\Batch\Model, 
    Akeneo\Component\BatchQueue\Queue, 
    Akeneo\Component\FileStorage\Model, 
    Pim\Component\Catalog\Model, 
    Akeneo\Component\Versioning\Model
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do custom code to achieve this. In Akeneo PIM, you can define which one of your family attribute **will be used as label** on the grid.

When you edit one of your family, you can select the attribute you want:
[image]

Once selected, you can save your family, and the selected attribute will be used as label in the grid (*only for products which belong to this family obviously*).

Let me know if I did not understand your real problem though.

Comment: I figured out this solution, but in my case I have different attributes I want to use as a label. For example: I want 'name' to be used for my products, but 'group_name' to be used for my product models. But I already figured out a working solution by extending `Pim\Bundle\DataGridBundle\Normalizer\ProductModelNormalizer::normalize()` and manipulating the `$data['label']`-property.

Comment: Ok, I see your problem now. Glad you found a solution. Indeed, this is the correct place to do this stuff!